# Should I use express route parameters to choose which callbacks to run, or should I declare the routes and callbacks explicitly?

Tags: express, routes

So, I have a route called `contact` which points to functions that pertain to a contact form.

I could do either:

```
// In routes.js
const contact = require('../controllers/contact');
app.post('contact/send', contact.send);
app.post('contact/upload', contact.upload);

// In controllers.js
exports.send = ...
exports.upload = ...
```

Or should I go with this method?

```
// In routes.js
const contact = require('../controllers/contact');
app.post('contact/:action', contact);

// In controllers.js
switch(req.param) {
  case 'send':
    //send code
    break;
  case 'upload':
    // upload code
    break;
  default:
    // default code
}
```

I'm asking this in the sense of which would make more sense or if one method is generally followed as a case of best practice for certain reasons.